# Extract data from .OUT file between 2 strings and create a new csv file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

My data is like below - stored in a .OUT file:

```
{ID=ISIN Name=yes PROGRAM=abc START_of_FIELDS CODE END-OF-FIELDS TIMESTARTED=Mon Nov 30 20:45:56
   START-OF-DATA 
CODE|ERR CODE|NUM|EXCH_CODE|
912828U rp|0|1|BERLIN|
1392917 rp|0|1|IND| 
3CB0248 rp|0|1|BRAZIL| 
END-OF-DATA***}
```

I need to extract the lines  between START-OF-DATA  and END-OF-DATA from above .OUT file using Python and load it in CSV file.

```
CODE|ERR CODE|NUM|EXCH_CODE|
912828U rp|0|1|BERLIN|
1392917 rp|0|1|IND|
3CB0248 rp|0|1|FRANKFURT|
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you able to show us the code you have tried so far and explain where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non greedy quantifier regex to get the entries between two strings.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
pattern = pattern = re.compile(r'(?:START-OF-DATA(.*?)END-OF-DATA)', re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
g = re.findall(pattern,data)

O/P
[' \nCODE|ERR CODE|NUM|EXCH_CODE|\n912828U rp|0|1|BERLIN|\n1392917 rp|0|1|IND| \n3CB0248 rp|0|1|BRAZIL| \n']

#remove whitespaces and split by new line and remove empty entries of list
t = g[0].replace(" ","").split("\n")
new = list(filter(None, t))

O/P
['CODE|ERRCODE|NUM|EXCH_CODE|', '912828Urp|0|1|BERLIN|', '1392917rp|0|1|IND|', '3CB0248rp|0|1|BRAZIL|']

#create dataframe with pipe demoted
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split('|') for i in new])

O/P

           0        1    2          3 
0       CODE  ERRCODE  NUM  EXCH_CODE  
1  912828Urp        0    1     BERLIN  
2  1392917rp        0    1        IND  
3  3CB0248rp        0    1     BRAZIL 

#create csv from df
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

The regex pattern defined here will capture everything whenever a match is found for a string that begins with "START-OF-DATA" and ends with "END-OF-DATA" and leave you its output

Comment: when i used this code import re
str = open("file_name.out","r")
a=print(str.read())
pattern = r'(?:START-OF-DATA(.*?)END-OF-DATA)'
re.findall(pattern,"a")----it just displays the content of the file.   when i use  myString = a.replace(' ', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '') it gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @Preetnayak You have assigned ```str``` to the file and working ```myString``` variable. However I have updated my answer to what you need, just utilise that and it will serve your purpose

Comment: Thanks i got ...but i have another issue is there any way to split the records after every 4 values...because i need to show this in a tabular way ..first the headers separated by PIPE delimeter and then values as shown in my initial screen shot..now i m getting everything as a single string

Comment: @Preetnayak I have updated the answer to what you require, this will be solve your purpose